# How to re-execute a specific task in ansible playbook?

Tags: apache, ansible, devops

I am writing a playbook to compile an Apache-2.4 from source. I would like to have the flow of playbook as follows:

1. Download source package in /usr/src
2. Extract it in the same folder.
3. Now, start compiling it. Run configure, make and make install.
4. In case, the last process fails due to dependency issues - like apr or apr-util. Call handler and download them, keep them in /usr/src/http-source/srclib/apr and /usr/src/http-source/srclib/apr-util.

After 3rd step, i would like to retry or re-execute 3rd step. How we can do this without writing a new step again? Any ideas??

This is what i have tried:-

```html
[root@system1 myansible]# cat apache_compile_simple.yml.
---
- hosts: system2*
  tasks:
   - name: Download the Apache source file
     get_url:
         url: http://www-us.apache.org/dist//httpd/httpd-2.4.29.tar.gz 
         dest: /usr/src/
     tags: download_source
   - name: Extract the source file 
     unarchive:
         src: /usr/src/httpd-2.4.29.tar.gz 
         dest: /usr/src/
         remote_src: yes
     tags: extract_source
   - name: Change the working directory
     command: chdir=/usr/src/httpd-2.4.29/ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-included-apr
     register: proc_status
     ignore_errors: true
     changed_when: false
     tags: configure
   - name: check for depencies
     debug: msg=""
     notify:  
       - apr
       - apr-util
     changed_when: "proc_status.rc != 0"
     tags: check_dep

  handlers:  
   - name: Install_dependencies
     get_url: url={{ item }} dest=/usr/src/
     with_items:
      - http://www-eu.apache.org/dist//apr/apr-1.6.3.tar.gz  
      - http://www-eu.apache.org/dist//apr/apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
     listen: "apr" 
   - name: ex_apr_dir_exist
     file:
      path: /usr/src/httpd-2.4.29/srclib/apr
      mode: 755
      state: directory 
      listen: "apr"
   - name: Unarchive the apr build   
     unarchive:
        src: /usr/src/apr-1.6.3.tar.gz
        dest: /usr/src/httpd-2.4.29/srclib/apr
        remote_src: yes 
     listen: "apr" 
   - name: Make apr-util directory
     file:
      path: /usr/src/httpd-2.4.29/srclib/apr-util
      mode: 755
      state: directory
     listen: "apr-util"
   - name: Unarchive the apr-utils build
     unarchive:
       src: /usr/src/apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
       dest: /usr/src/httpd-2.4.29/srclib/apr-util
       remote_src: yes
     listen: "apr-util"
```

I would like to get ideas on how to re-execute "configure apache" task, after the handler is done.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ansible's docs on reusable playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse.html).  To answer your question directly you could create a separate file with the "cofigure apache" task and use `include_tasks` to reuse the same task in your main playbook and handlers.

However, I think it would make more sense to check for dependencies and install them first before installing apache.  Handlers are intended for when something on the system has changed and a subsequent action is required (i.e. - config for service x has been changed, restart service x).

Comment: Thanks Kfreezy!! I have gone through the above mentioned link. It seems to be pretty useful. However, i am little confused between static and dynamic reference of usage of import and include tasks. Could you please explain it in a lucid way.

Comment: Imports are processed at the start when the playbook is parsed and includes are processed when the playbook reaches those tasks.  I really wouldn't stress too much about it since you could use either one in this case.  The main differences are that group/host vars aren't included in static imports and that you can only loop over dynamic includes.